# Phase Unwrapping Behaving Oddly For Optics Simulation

Tags: discrete-signals, python, phase

In short, I am coding an optics simulation for an experiment I am running. There is a point where I perform a Fourier transform on my incoming signal and want to extract the phase; however, I get unexpected results.

More specifically, I want to unwrap the phase from the signal below:

[image]
To extract the phase I use the following function:

```
def phase_extractor(fourier, t_max, t):     
   
    phase = np.angle(fourier)
    
    # Unwrap the phase to remove jumps or discontinuities
    phase_spectrum = np.unwrap(phase)
    #proper_phase = torch.from_numpy(phase_realtime)
    return phase_spectrum
```

Ignore the t_max and t inputs - they aren't of interest for now

After running the function on this input data and simply plotting the phase spectrum, I get the following result:

[image]

I was expecting it to have discrete steps at pi intervals (i.e., it would look like a staircase with steps of height pi).

So far in terms of debugging, I have done the following:

1. After using np.angle() I checked the difference between consecutive elements in a list and the maximum was pi, so that tells me resolution isn't an issue.
2. I've tried doing an fftshift of my data so that unwrapping starts at the zero-frequency; however that doesn't change much - the only notable difference is a small bump in the centre of the output.

If anyone knows about phase unwrapping and could help me out that'd be great. I am not too familiar with phase unwrapping and have had some major difficulty debugging this

Edit:
Sorry for any clarity issues, this is *very crudely* what I was expecting (i.e., a staircase type function with height of ~pi):

[image]

Edit #2:

Here is the original signal - note I am trying to get the information from the target. Also, regarding the phase plot, y-axis is the phase in radians and the x-axis is simply the array index.
[image]

Comment: but you eliminate the $\pi$ jumps intentionally with `np.unwrap`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, No... isn't the point of phase unwrapping to view that behaviour? Also when I remove the np.unwrap I just get two blobs which doesn't make much sense

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  As Marcus says, the point of `np.unwrap` is to remove the +/- $\pi$ jumps in the phase that happen because complex number phase can only usually be found within the range $[-\pi,+\pi)$, but complex functions of, say, frequency have phases that vary over a much larger range.  Can you please include a (perhaps hand-drawn) plot of what you're expecting to see?

Comment: @PeterK. ahh that makes sense, thank you. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Your axis aren't labelled so I can't tell with the phase is in radians or degrees. In any case,  it's a mostly linear phase which probably means that your time signal isn't centered round zero.  You can post your signal before the FFT ?

Comment: @Hilmar See the new edit - I think I addressed your question. My signal is centered around 0

Comment: @user68185: how do you represent negative time in your code ? Is the time data arranged so that the first sample represents  $t=0$ or is $t=0$ in the middle of the array. Other than that: the time domain data looks symmetrical so we would expect the phase to be mostly 0. Why do you think there are should be a staircase function in the phase ?